# Validating string value has the correct XML format

Tags: c#

I am Having a sring  for which  i need to chek weather it has correct XML format like consistent start and end tags.

Sorry i tried to make string value well formated but could not :).

```
string parameter="<HostName>Arasanalu</HostName><AdminUserName>Administrator</AdminUserName><AdminPassword>A1234</AdminPassword><placeNumber>38</PlaceNumber>"
```

I tried with following check :

```
public bool IsValidXML(string value)
{
    try
    {
        // Check we actually have a value
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) == false)
        {
            // Try to load the value into a document
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

            xmlDoc.LoadXml(parameter);

            // If we managed with no exception then this is valid XML!
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            // A blank value is not valid xml
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (System.Xml.XmlException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It was throwing error for correct as well as wrong format.

Please let me know how can i proceed.

Regards,
Channa

Comment: There is no format for checking this It will only get caught in exception

Comment: is this a typo `<<AdminUserName>` ? and whatz with the `<BR>` at the end ?

Comment: yes typo  actual string is string parameter=
"<HostName>Arasanalu</HostName> <<AdminUserName>Administrator</AdminUserName><AdminPassword>A1234</AdminPassword><placeNumber>38</PlaceNumber>";

Comment: Well if its a formatting issue still you do not have a **root element** for it to be a proper xml document

Comment: Ok so can i use the format like :                                                               XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();                                                                  xDoc.LoadXml("<root>" + ab + "</root>");

Comment: Yes that would a root element and it should work (Hope the `placeNumber` is also in the same casing )

Comment: Thanks it is working now by adding <root> +mystring+ <root>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of the string you have do not actually form a valid xml document

Its missing a Root Element

```
string parameter="<HostName>Arasanalu</HostName><AdminUserName>Administrator</AdminUserName><AdminPassword>A1234</AdminPassword><PlaceNumber>38</PlaceNumber>";
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(); \
doc.LoadXml("<root>" + parameter + "</root>"); // this adds a root element and makes it Valid
```

[Root Element](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-root)

> There is exactly one element, called the root, or document element, no
>   part of which appears in the content of any other element.] For all
>   other elements, if the start-tag is in the content of another element,
>   the end-tag is in the content of the same element. More simply stated,
>   the elements, delimited by start- and end-tags, nest properly within
>   each other.

Answer (score 0):

Always put proper tags in variable. Put `<root>` tag before and after you code. Try below code.

```
        try
        {
            string unformattedXml = "<Root><HostName>Arasanalu</HostName><AdminUserName>Administrator</AdminUserName><AdminPassword>A1234</AdminPassword><PlaceNumber>38</PlaceNumber></Root>";
            string formattedXml = XElement.Parse(unformattedXml).ToString();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your code : i was unable to call XElement.parse.

Comment: i was unable to call XElement.parse.                                                       XmlElement xmlelement =new XmlElement();                                                                  xmlelement.parse does not exist : do we need to include any ?

Comment: Use using `System.Xml.Linq;`